# Install Ubuntu but GRUB console opens

Tags: system-installation

i'm encountering an issue while trying to install Ubuntu from a bootable USB drive, and i'm getting stuck at the GRUB console.but how To resolve this issue,

Comment: You've provided few specific details; what Ubuntu product?, what release of that product?, what architecture are you installing on? how did you write the ISO to media? (*incorrect write methods can cause boot loader to fail to write correctly*) and which ISO did you opt to use? (ie. which installer, as some product/releases have different installers selected by the ISO you download & use).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)